# Laravel foreign key nullable can not be null on UPDATE

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I create a table- GAllERY_ID on POST. That is a foreign key nullable, and null as default.
When I create a POST, if I don't set the GALLERY_ID, it will be null.
But if I set the GALLERY_ID and reference on a GAllery, after if I try to make this NULL again (ON UPDATE ), I can´t.

I did like this the migration -

UP –

```
$table->integer(‘gallery_id’)->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);

$table->foreign(‘gallery_id’)->references(‘id’)->on(‘photo_gallery’);
```

DOWN –

```
$table->dropForeign(‘posts_gallery_id_foreign’);
```

[Have a look on the image of my DB on PHP MY ADMIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtqqg.jpg)

If I go on PHP my admin I can update this value, just checking NULL on Gallery ID, BUT in my code on UPDATE, if I set like this -

```
$post->gallery_id      =  Null;
```

It will give this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...

Because I can't set null a foreign key to Update, just on a created method, if I don't set, it will be null, but if I set a value and after I try to change to NULL, I can't.

Some one can help me?

Comment: Please try `$post->attributes['gallery_id'] = NULL;`

Comment: Hello my friend , Thanks for the fast answering .
I tried this code on the controller  , but its gives me an error -


ErrorException in NoticiasController.php line 361:
Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Post::$attributes has no effect


I tried this code as well on the model like this  -

 public function setGalleryIdAttribute(){
        $this->attributes['gallery_id'] = NULL;
    }


But it didnt make any difference , it still givng the same error , and It does not aloud to me to change to a Null value after I set a reference .

Comment: Okey! in your migration try: `$table->foreign(‘gallery_id’)->references(‘id’)->on(‘photo_gallery’)->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('SET NULL');`. You are welcome ;)

Comment: Is this on UP or on Down method ?

Comment: Rollback the migration then add it to UP the commit ;)

Comment: It is still giving the same error  - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...

Comment: I tried on UP method -
$table->foreign('gallery_id')->references('id')->on('photo_gallery')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('SET NULL');

as well 


$table->foreign('gallery_id')->references('id')->on('photo_gallery')->onUpdate('cascade'|'restrict'|'set null'|'no action');

Ass well

$table->foreign('gallery_id')->references('id')->on('photo_gallery')->onUpdate('set null')->change();